# GeoJSON: get Type of Feature?

Tags: typescript, geojson, react-leaflet

I cannot find the right type for [*GeoJSON* features](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.2) by using *react-leaflet* and TypeScript.

I can import the namespace

```
import { GeoJSON [...] } from 'react-leaflet';
```

store the `FeatureCollection`

```
export type TFeatureColl = GeoJSON.FeatureCollection;
```

and then get in a Tooltip of VSCode for an array of *features* like `const newGeo :TFeatureColl ...; newGeo.features.map(...`:

```
(property) FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>.features: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>[]
```

#### But I cannot get the right type of the argument *feature* in my *style* callback

```
 <GeoJSON key={new Date().toISOString()} data={data as TFeatureColl} onEachFeature={handleFeature} style={styleFeature}/>

const styleFeature = useCallback((feat /* cannot be found: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>*/) :PathOptions => {
        // shows 'any' for 'properties'
        const props = feat.properties;
        if (!props) {
            return /* some stuff */;
        }

        // problem here: 'osm_id' is missing in props validation
        const osmId = props.osm_id;
        return {
            // would be defined by some data
            fillColor: '#0a0',
            color: '#f0' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        };
    }, []);
```

Is there any way to find the right type for a single *feature*?

I have searched the repository of *react-leaflet*, *@types/react-leaflet*, Google - nothing came up. VSCode can find the type somehow (again, based on `GeoJSON` from *react-leaflet*), but do not offer the source.

#### Even if I try to use the GeoJSON namespace for typing it fails:

```
/*
TS2322: Type '(feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry, GeoJSON.GeoJsonProperties>) => PathOptions' is not assignable to type 'PathOptions | StyleFunction<any> | undefined'.
  Type '(feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry, GeoJSON.GeoJsonProperties>) => PathOptions' is not assignable to type 'StyleFunction<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'feature' and 'feature' are incompatible.
      Type 'Feature<Geometry, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>'.
*/
const styleFeature = useCallback((feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry, GeoJSON.GeoJsonProperties>) :PathOptions => {
const osmId = props.osm_id;
}), []);
```

So here I do not get the right type for the callback of `style={func}` - and I am lost.

### Edit

#### Solution for now:

```
const styleFeature = useCallback((feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry, any> | undefined) :PathOptions => {
    const props = feature && feature.properties;
    const properties = props as GeoJSON.GeoJsonProperties;
    if (!properties) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}, []);
```

**I did not find any [docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#geojson) (or [tests](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-leaflet/react-leaflet-tests.tsx#L873)) for this.**